# Expected a type error in 'myproj'-Bridging-Header.swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, gif

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQAdL.png)When I add UIIMage+Gif.swift file to my Objective C project to add GIF images in Swift files inside my Obj-C project I got "expected a type" error in generated swift header file.

```
+ (double)delayForImageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index source:(CGImageSourceRef _Null_unspecified)source;
+ (UIImage * _Nullable)animatedImageWithSource:(CGImageSourceRef _Nonnull)source;
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple,

add new file by right clicking on left panel where all objective c file and add new file and name it uiimage+gif its working

Comment: i already added a new swift file and named it UIImage+Gif and inserted the code inside it and run i got compile error in auto generated swift file 'expected a type'